# Service to nicely print a huge E-textbook?

Tags: pdf, printed

I found an awesome textbook for my language studies. It is freely available as a pdf file, a Word document, as well as a browsable website.
For me, language study involves taking a lot of notes in my textbooks, connecting together the pieces of information I already acquired and understood, adding color to make grammar patterns emerge, etc.
For that reason, I want to physically print that textbook. However, it is more than 600 pages, and I can't find a place where I could print and bind those into a nice looking book.

Is there an online service that could print, bind, and send me the textbook, if I provide them with the pdf/doc file?
Bonus points if this service is located in - or can ship to - Japan.

Update: Additional information
The book is for personal use only, I will not sell it.
I found that printed versions were selling starting from 160$ on Amazon (unfortunately the sellers do not ship to my country). I am looking for less costly alternatives.

Comment: Check this page for what topics are appropriate for this site: https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @idiotprogrammer Thank you for the link, I could not find easily that information on the Android StackExchange app. Do you have a suggestion of other sites where this question would fit well?

Comment: There are lots of things that are freely available on the internet, that are actually not free (i.e. illegal copies), and could get you into trouble if you try to print them. There are several [service providers in the USA](https://tech-vise.com/best-parcel-forwarding-services-for-international-shoppers/) that will forward to foreign countries for a modest fee. That way you can buy the printed version in the USA and still receive it in Japan after a modest delay

Answer (score 1):

This is a shopping/recommendation question, which is generally not appropriate for this site.

I have to assume that you want the printed book for personal use and not to sell to other people. I also have to assume that you don't care about how the cover looks and that you want something bound. But you didn't mention how many copies you want or how much you wish to spend. These last two points are important.

I am not really recommending this store, but this business site lists various packages for printing books. http://www.officedepot.com/a/copy-and-print/presentations/ This will give you an idea about terminology for the different types of printing.

I think it's better to talk to someone at a local print shop. Such a person might have a better idea which kind of binding is most suitable for your budget and for page length.

Another option might be to look through the various print-on-demand services. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-4-online-selfpublishers-book-write/
(contrary to what this article says, I think Createspace is a good print-on-demand service). The main problems with these POD services is that they assume that you have a PDF ready for printing according to their specs, and you are probably not in a position to modify the formatting.

Comment: Thank you for those links. I also updated my original question to answer about the information you asked about.

Comment: Hmm I can't access the OfficeDepot site, I only get an "Access Denied" message page.

Comment: Wow, how strange. Officedepot is a major business services company. Perhaps they block access from users outside the US? Try this: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KnDs_b2eh_sJ:www.officedepot.com/a/copy-and-print/presentations/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us